# how to update a LOB with PHP in oracle? (OCI_INVALID_HANDLE)

Tags: php, oracle, oracle11g

i'm trying to do an update a (C)LOB in the same way i do an insert. (insert is already working).

```
$queryHandle = oci_parse($dbHandle, "update MYTABLE set "MYCLOB" = EMPTY_CLOB() , "OTHERCOL" = :col0 where "PKIDCOL" = :wherecol0 returning "OTHERCOL" , "MYCLOB", into :retcol0 , :retcol1");
if(!is_resource($queryHandle)) {
$error=oci_error($dbHandle);
die($error['message'], $error['code']);
}
oci_bind_by_name($queryHandle, ":col0", $othercolvalue);
oci_bind_by_name($queryHandle, ":wherecol0", $pkidcol);
oci_bind_by_name($queryHandle, ":retcol0", $retcol1, 100);
$lob=oci_new_descriptor($dbHandle);
oci_bind_by_name($queryHandle, ":retcol1", $lob, -1, SQLT_CLOB);
if(!oci_execute($queryHandle , OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT)) {
$error=oci_error($dbHandle);
die($error['message'], $error['code']);
}
$lob->save($mylobvalue);  // gives an  PHP Warning:  OCI-Lob::save(): OCI_INVALID_HANDLE in file.php on line 123
```

this does not update the lob and gives an: `PHP Warning:  OCI-Lob::save(): OCI_INVALID_HANDLE in file.php on line 123`

Comment: This is mentioned in documentation: `If you are using Save() on an update statement, PHP will throw a warning similar to "OCILobWrite: OCI_INVALID_HANDLE..." if your update statement did not catch any rows with its where clause.` So before you update database you need to be sure, that your condition is matched. In your example `$queryHandle` is valid for saving.

Comment: thanks. it was indeed this issue. :-)

Answer (score 2):

There are dozens of examples of how to insert/update a row with a `LOB` value.

First of all, you have to create a `LOB` descriptor:

```php
$desc = oci_new_descriptor($connection, OCI_DTYPE_LOB);
```

Then use this descriptor as your binding value for the `LOB` placeholder:

```php
oci_bind_by_name($queryHandle, ":retcol1", $desc, -1, SQLT_CLOB);
```

Then temporary write the data:

```php
$desc->writeTemporary($data);
```

And after that execute that query...

More information could be find at the [documentation](http://php.net/oci_new_descriptor) + read carefully all the comments for more examples!

Some examples use `$desc->write($data);` + execute + commit, some use execute + `$desc->saveFile($data);` + commit, all should work.

Answer (score 0):

As PLB said: the update query did not update any rows due to a wrong primary key value. This led to the php warning message.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/fuecks-lobs-095315.html