# OCI_INVALID_HANDLE When Calling Oracle Procedure

Tags: php, plsql, blob, email-attachments

I'm trying to write a PHP function that calls an oracle procedure to send an email with an attachment, I have the oracle procedure written, based on the one described here, using a BLOB as attachment, http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/email-from-oracle-plsql.php

However, when calling my PHP function I get a **Warning** saying:

```
Warning: OCI-Lob::save(): OCI_INVALID_HANDLE in /public_html/classes/oracle.php on line 683
```

The function I'm calling to send the email is this one:

```
public function sendmail_attachment($p_from, $p_to, $p_cc, $p_reply, $p_subject, $p_body, $p_attach_name, $p_attach_mime, $p_attach_blob) {
    $result = '';

    $stid = oci_parse($this->conn, "begin 
                                      send_email_attach (:p1,:p2,:p3,:p4,:p5,:p6,:p7,:p8,:p9); 
                                    end;");

    // Creates an "empty" OCI-Lob object to bind to the locator
    $myLOB = oci_new_descriptor($this->conn, OCI_D_LOB);

    oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':p1', $p_from);
    oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':p2', $p_to);
    oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':p3', $p_cc);
    oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':p4', $p_reply);

    oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':p5', $p_subject);
    oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':p6', $p_body);
    oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':p7', $p_attach_name);
    oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':p8', $p_attach_mime);
    oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':p9', $myLOB, -1, OCI_B_BLOB);

    $contents = file_get_contents($p_attach_blob['tmp_name']);



    // Now save a value to the LOB
    if ( !$myLOB->save($contents) ) {

        // On error, rollback the transaction
        oci_rollback($this->conn);

    } else {

    oci_execute($stid, OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT);
        oci_commit($this->conn);
    }

    // Free resources
    oci_free_statement($stid);
    $myLOB->free();
}
```

As I've changed the PL/SQL procedure, and due to privacy I will not be posting what that procedure contains however I will post the part about attaching a file

```
  IF p_attach_name IS NOT NULL THEN
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, '--' || l_boundary || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Content-Type: ' || p_attach_mime || '; name="' || p_attach_name || '"' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' || p_attach_name || '"' || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);

    FOR i IN 0 .. TRUNC((DBMS_LOB.getlength(p_attach_blob) - 1 )/l_step) LOOP
      UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, UTL_RAW.cast_to_varchar2(UTL_ENCODE.base64_encode(DBMS_LOB.substr(p_attach_blob, l_step, i * l_step + 1))));
    END LOOP;

    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  END IF;
```

Does anyone know the issue to this please, and if so know how to fix it would be a great help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to update a LOB with PHP in oracle? (OCI_INVALID_HANDLE)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16540226/how-to-update-a-lob-with-php-in-oracle-oci-invalid-handle)

Comment: CLOBs and BLOBs are different and act differently in PHP, not a duplicate